# Why Am I getting a run time error on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

before i begin i am very new to programming and excel vba so please be nice.
i am attempting to make a program to automatically create balanced teams for friendly games of starcraft 2 based on an ongoing spreadsheet of our win loss ratios.

Here is a simplified version of that spreadsheet

[the simplified spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFy1H.png)

I am then trying to use vba code to run through every possible team configuration and find two teams where the difference between the sum of the win/loss ratios are the smallest.

here is my code i hope u can understand all the variable names

```
        Public Sub Main()
    Dim TotalScore As Integer
    TotalScore = 0
   Dim TargetScore As Integer
    TargetScore = 0
    Dim CurrentScore As Integer
    CurrentScore = 0
    Dim InitialScoreDifference As Integer
    InitialScoreDifference = 0
    Dim ScoreDifference As Integer
    ScoreDifference = 0
   Dim Scores(0 To 7) As Long
    Scores(0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "D").Value
    Scores(1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "D").Value
    Scores(2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "D").Value
    Scores(3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, "D").Value
    Scores(4) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, "D").Value
    Scores(5) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, "D").Value
    Scores(6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, "D").Value
    Scores(7) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, "D").Value
        For x = 0 To Scores(7)
            TotalScore = TotalScore + Scores(x)
        Next x
        TargetScore = Int(TotalScore / 2)
        InitialScoreDifference = (TotalScore)
        Console.WriteLine (TotalScore)
        Console.WriteLine (TargetScore)
        Console.WriteLine (InitialScoreDifference)
        For a = 0 To Scores(7)
            For b = 0 To Scores(7)
                For c = 0 To Scores(7)
                    For d = 0 To Scores(7)
                        CurrentScore = (Scores(a) + Scores(b) + Scores(c) + Scores(d))
                        ScoreDifference = ((TargetScore - CurrentScore) * (TargetScore - CurrentScore))
                        If ScoreDifference <= InitialScoreDifference Then

                            If ((Scores(a) <> Scores(b)) And (Scores(a) <> Scores(c)) And (Scores(a) <> Scores(d)) And (Scores(b) <> Scores(c)) And (Scores(b) <> Scores(d)) And (Scores(c) <> Scores(d))) Then
                                InitialScoreDifference = ScoreDifference
                                Console.WriteLine (Scores(a) & " " & Scores(b) & " " & Scores(c) & " " & Scores(d) & " " & ScoreDifference)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next d
                Next c
            Next b
        Next a
  End Sub
```

When i run the code on visual studios it works fine and gives me the combination of 4 win/loss scores that will balance the teams. However when i run it on excel vba i keep getting :
run-time error "9"
subscript out off range

finally, i realise the algorithm im using is very inefficient and that i should be using a recursion algorithm for this kind of stuff, but i didnt really understand recursion so this was the next best thing

thank u for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 2):

In vba you can't write

`Console.WriteLine (TotalScore)`

Instead write

`Debug.Print TotalScore`

You should also declare `Long` instead of `Integer` to avoid overflow, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare all your variables e.g.

As I think you are looping the whole array it is probably better to avoid hardcoding the bounds as you might increase the size of the array in the future so maybe, assuming you have a sheet called "Sheet1" in the currently ActiveWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    Dim TotalScore As Long
    Dim TargetScore As Long
    Dim CurrentScore As Long
    Dim InitialScoreDifference As Long
    Dim ScoreDifference As Long

    TotalScore = 0
    TargetScore = 0
    CurrentScore = 0
    InitialScoreDifference = 0
    ScoreDifference = 0

    Dim Scores(0 To 7) As Long
    Scores(0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "D").Value
    Scores(1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "D").Value
    Scores(2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "D").Value
    Scores(3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, "D").Value
    Scores(4) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, "D").Value
    Scores(5) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, "D").Value
    Scores(6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, "D").Value
    Scores(7) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, "D").Value

    Dim x As Long

    For x = LBound(Scores) To UBound(Scores)
        TotalScore = TotalScore + Scores(x)
    Next x

    TargetScore = CLng(TotalScore / 2)
    InitialScoreDifference = (TotalScore)

    Debug.Print "TotalScore: " & TotalScore
    Debug.Print "TargetScore: " & TargetScore
    Debug.Print "InitialScoreDifference: " & InitialScoreDifference

    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long

    For a = LBound(Scores) To UBound(Scores)
        For b = LBound(Scores) To UBound(Scores)
            For c = LBound(Scores) To UBound(Scores)
                For d = LBound(Scores) To UBound(Scores)
                    CurrentScore = (Scores(a) + Scores(b) + Scores(c) + Scores(d))
                    ScoreDifference = (TargetScore - CurrentScore) * (TargetScore - CurrentScore)
                    If ScoreDifference <= InitialScoreDifference Then
                        If ((Scores(a) <> Scores(b)) And (Scores(a) <> Scores(c)) And (Scores(a) <> Scores(d)) And (Scores(b) <> Scores(c)) And (Scores(b) <> Scores(d)) And (Scores(c) <> Scores(d))) Then
                            InitialScoreDifference = ScoreDifference
                            Debug.Print (Scores(a) & " " & Scores(b) & " " & Scores(c) & " " & Scores(d) & " " & ScoreDifference)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Console.WriteLine` is VB.Net Syntax. For VBA it is `Debug.Print` like QHarr suggested.
2. In VB.Net `Integer` can hold signed 32-bit (4-byte) integers that range in value from `2,147,483,648` through `2,147,483,647`. In VBA `Integer` can hold value from `32,768` to `32,767`. And hence it is advisable to use `Long` in VBA.
3. No need to declare an array and manully fill it. Declare a `Variant` and fill the array at run time. For example

   ```
   Dim Scores(0 To 7) As Long
   Scores(0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "D").Value
   Scores(1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "D").Value
   Scores(2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "D").Value
   Scores(3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, "D").Value
   Scores(4) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, "D").Value
   Scores(5) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, "D").Value
   Scores(6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, "D").Value
   Scores(7) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, "D").Value
   ```

   can be written as

   ```
   Dim Scores As Variant
   Scores = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D9").Value
   ```

   and then you can use them as

   ```
   CurrentScore = (Scores(a, 1) + Scores(b, 1) + Scores(c, 1) + Scores(d, 1))
   ```
4. To find the sum, again you do not need to loop though the array, you can directly find the sum of the range using `Application.Evaluate`. For example

   ```
   TotalScore = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(Sheet1!D2:D9)")
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: To sum the array, you can also just use `TotalScore = WorksheetFunction.Sum(scores)`

Comment: @Chronocidal: True that :)